# get current user and save to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, post

**Based on suggestions and a better understanding of what I need I have changed my question:**

My site is protected with **.htaccess**. Im trying to get the current user and a few other variables and save them to  a **MySQL** database. Everything works except the **current user** part.

Heres my code:

```
<?php

            $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] = "rep";
            $hostname = "hostname";
            $username = "username";
            $dbname = "dbname";

        $password = "password";
            $usertable = "usageStats";
            $yourfield = "your_field";


$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO usageStats (Bid, PRid, User)
VALUES
('$_POST[BID]','$_POST[branding]','$_POST[rep]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I know that the below are both wrong. How should the current user be passed instead of  $_POST[rep]?

**Wong:**

```
$_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] = "rep";
```

and

```
'$_POST[rep]'
```

Comment: What type of authentication are you using? Is it basic authentication?

Comment: Don't rely on hidden fields for authentication. This can easily be spoofed.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov yes Im using basic authentication.

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche what do you mean by "Don't rely on hidden fields for authentication" im not using the form to log the user in but rather the form is presented after the user has logged in and I want to set the value of "currentUser" so that it passes the user name with the form submission. Or am I misunderstanding you ?

Comment: If this hidden field is the only token to identify the user, someone else could send a request with this hidden field, claiming to be a user of your site.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah I see your concern. I dont think thatll be an issue in this case though. THe users login elsewhere. This form really just takes info the user supplies, formats it differently then shows it back to the user and saves it to a database. Im just looking for a way to save the user's username with that info.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Basic Authentication` you do not need to send the username explicitly. The browser will send it and you can access it using the `PHP_AUTH_USER` server variable:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
```

Also checkout the [`HTTP Authentication`](https://www.php.net/features.http-auth) article in the documentation.

Comment: Darin, I tried to implement what you suggested but I cant get the call right. Would you mind taking a look at my edit above please?